# Symfony 2 Doctrine LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join

I have 3 tables in DB:
task_estimation_fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_estimation_fields` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

task_estimations:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_estimations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_estimation_field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `summary` blob,
  `effort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `g1` (`task_id`),
  KEY `g2` (`created_by`),
  KEY `g3` (`task_estimation_field_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `g1` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION         ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `g2` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `g3` FOREIGN KEY (`task_estimation_field_id`) REFERENCES     `task_estimation_fields` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

tasks:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assignee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prioryty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Entity files generated from existing database using following commands:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

And I want to get results of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM task_estimation_fields tef LEFT JOIN task_estimations te ON (tef.id = te.task_estimation_field_id AND te.task_id = 1)
```

I am using symfony 2.4.3 and I have generated following code:

```
$estimations = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('tef, te')
                ->from('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimationFields', 'tef')
                ->leftJoin('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimations', 'te', 'WITH', 'tef.id = te.task_estimation_field_id AND te.task_id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

The problem is that i am getting following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 133 near 'task_estimation_field_id': Error: Class Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimations has no field or association named task_estimation_field_id
```

And thats true that in Entity there is no such field but there is:

```
/**
 * @var \Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_estimation_field_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $taskEstimationField;
```

Which covers the relation.

Whene I remove relation from queryBuilder:

```
$estimations = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('tef, te')
            ->from('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimationFields', 'tef')
            ->leftJoin('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimations', 'te', 'WITH', 'te.task_id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I am receiving:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 124 near 'task_id = :i': Error: Class Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimations has no field or association named task_id
```

Which is also true because in Entity it is covered by:

```
/**
 * @var \Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\Tasks
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\Tasks")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $task;
```

How to get results i need?
How to print those results in twig?

Comment: Use entity field names in your queries `te.task = :id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DQL queries you need to use the **association name** not the **column name**.

In your case you need to use `te.taskEstimationField` instead of `te.task_estimation_field_id` and `te.task` instead of `te.task_id`.

Comment: Works :) THX :D And how to print it in twig? I using such code in TWIG:     
    {% for es in estimations %}
        {{ es.description2 }}</br>
    {% endfor %}

And i am getting: 

    Method "description" for object "Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields" does not exist in SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index.html.twig at line 7

Comment: You should ask a separate question about that -- they're not very related to one another.

Comment: Either way I would need to see more code from your controller -- I don't know how you're passing the query results to Twig,

Comment: I have created a new question with detailed description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381593/symfony2-database-results-in-twig