# Symfony2 Database results in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have 3 tables in DB:

*task_estimation_fields*:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_estimation_fields` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

*task_estimations*:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_estimations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_estimation_field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `summary` blob,
  `effort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `g1` (`task_id`),
  KEY `g2` (`created_by`),
  KEY `g3` (`task_estimation_field_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `g1` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION         ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `g2` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `g3` FOREIGN KEY (`task_estimation_field_id`) REFERENCES     `task_estimation_fields` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

*tasks*:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assignee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prioryty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Entity files generated from existing database using following commands:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

In the controler I am getting resulte from database this way:

```
public function indexAction($id) {
        $estimations = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('tef, te')
                ->from('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimationFields', 'tef')
                ->leftJoin('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimations', 'te', 'WITH', 'te.taskEstimationField = tef.id AND te.task = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

        if (!$this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->render('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index.html.twig', array('id' => $id, 'estimations' => $estimations));
        } else {
            return $this->render('SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index_ajax.html.twig', array('id' => $id, 'estimations' => $estimations));
        }
    }
```

The Twig code is here:

```
{% extends 'SynapthsisSpecBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block page_contener %}
    task estimation index {{ id }}
    <hr />
    {% for es in estimations %}
        {{ es.description }}</br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that I am getting:

```
Method "description" for object "Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields" does not exist in SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index.html.twig at line 7
```

So I thought that I am getting *TaskEstimations* so i wanted to show "name" field with code like this:

```
{% extends 'SynapthsisSpecBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block page_contener %}
    task estimation index {{ id }}
    <hr />
    {% for es in estimations %}
        {% if null != es %}
            {{ es.name }}</br>
        {% else %}
            aaa </br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting:

```
Method "effort" for object "Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields" does not exist in SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index.html.twig at line 7
```

How can I print results of the query above in the TWIG template?

Comment: The `TaskEstimation.description` is a `blob` (file?) - how can you print it? It doesn't make sens? This field is for long taxt description or a file? If it is for text it should be defined as `text`.

Comment: I don't think Doctrine supports blob. Change this to Text and make sure it's changed in the Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$estimations` variable is an array of Objects `TaskEstimationFields` so you can't get `description`. Try this:

Change your query form `->getResult();` to `->getScalarResult();`

Then print effort like this

```
{% for es in estimations %}
    {{ es.te_effort }}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

Then `es` should be something like this:

```
array (size=8)
  'tef_name' => string 'somename' (length=8)
  'tef_id' => int 1
  'te_description' => resource(52, stream)
  'te_summary' => resource(54, stream)
  'te_effort' => int 123
  'te_createdAt' => 
    object(DateTime)[307]
      public 'date' => string '2014-04-30 11:19:20' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Warsaw' (length=13)
  'te_createdBy' => int 1
  'te_id' => int 3
```

And you can print it like this:

```
{% for es in estimations %}
    {{ es.tef_name }}</br>
    {{ es.te_summary }}</br>
    (...)
    {{ es.te_createdAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
    (...)
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Method "taskEstimation" for object "Synapthsis\SpecBundle\Entity\TaskEstimationFields" does not exist in SynapthsisSpecBundle:TaskEstimation:index.html.twig at line 7

Comment: Did you try `{{ dump(es) }}` to see whats inside `es`?

Comment: And with dump(es) nothing is shown (totally empty page) in PHP ERROR LOG i got [30-Apr-2014 11:00:13 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123207680 bytes) in D:\apps\www\Specification_Server\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php on line 66      - in php.ini i have 
memory_limit = 128M